# How to fix the url bar not updating

Tags: python

you may of noticed I've been asking alot of questions about my web browser and It's because I'm a newb too these things and  asking questions is the way I understand, and get better and learn obviously.

So, my question is as said in the title how to fix the problem where the url doesn't update when I click on another link, here is a image to show  what I mean:

[image]

As you can see, I've searched 'test' in google. Now, if you take a look at the URL bar where it says `google.com` It has not updated witch I should be showing

```
https://www.google.com.au/search?q=test&oq=test&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l2.1134j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
```

I'm using Quickly to build my app.

Here is my source code for the browser:

```
self.refreshbutton = self.builder.get_object("refreshbutton")
    self.urlentry = self.builder.get_object("urlentry")
    self.scrolledwindow = self.builder.get_object("scrolledwindow")
    self.backbutton = self.builder.get_object("backbutton")
    self.forwardbutton = self.builder.get_object("forwardbutton")

    self.webview = WebKit.WebView()

    self.scrolledwindow.add(self.webview)
    self.webview.show()

def on_refreshbutton_clicked(self, widget):
    self.webview.reload()

def on_backbutton_clicked(self, widget):
    self.webview.go_back()

def on_forwardbutton_clicked(self, widget):
    self.webview.go_forward()

def on_urlentry_activate(self, widget):
    url = widget.get_text()

    self.webview.open(url)
```

Got any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: On my computer it just shows `https://www.google.com/#q=test`; what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an event handler for the webview's `load_committed` event then change the text in your `urlentry` text box to reflect the current url

```
    ...
    self.webview = WebKit.WebView()
    self.webview.connect('load_committed', self.change_url)

    self.scrolledwindow.add(self.webview)
    self.webview.show()

def change_url(self, widget, data=None):
    self.urlentry.set_text( widget.get_main_frame().get_uri() )

...
```

Comment: I get a error. self.urlentry.set_text( widget.get_main_frame().get_uri() )

Comment: try changing `widget.get_main_frame().get_uri()` to `self.webview.get_uri()`

Comment: Here's another error for you. AttributeError: 'WebtigerWindow' object has no attribute 'webkit'

Comment: Sorry, the `webkit` should be `webview` - copy and paste fail :P

Comment: Thankyou so much, question in mind any way you could help me off the website, there's so many questions in my head witch would be annoying to keep posting?